# Unable to open SQLite database from singleton object

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, singleton, android-sqlite, android-context

I am able to open the database from within the main app activity using the following code, but once it's wrapped into a singleton object, it keeps throwing a null-object error:

```
object CommonClass {

    fun openSQLDatabase(): SQLiteDatabase? {
        var dbase: SQLiteDatabase? = null
        try {
            dbase = openOrCreateDatabase(
                "dbfile.sqlite",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null
            )
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            println(e.message)
        }
        return dbase
    }

}
```

I'm assuming that the main **AppCompatActivity** should be passing its context to the object in some way, but I've not been able to find a working model.

---

**to Swayangjit**

Android Studio highlights the **Context.MODE_PRIVATE** parameter and flags it as:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?
Found: Int
```

But when I implement the **AppCompatActivity** to the singleton object and pass the **Context.MODE_PRIVATE** from the main activity, it runs but throws this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @Swayangjit I've edited my question with the required info. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will work :

```
object CommonClass {

    fun openSQLDatabase(context: Context): SQLiteDatabase? {
        var dbase: SQLiteDatabase? = null
        if (dbase == null) {
            try {
                dbase = openOrCreateDatabase(context.getDatabasePath("dbfile.sqlite"), null)
            } catch (e: SQLException) {
                println(e.message)
            }
        }
        return dbase
    }
}
```

Note this assumes that you want the database in the default location i.e. `data/data/the_package_name/databases/dbfile.sqlite`

You could invoke/call it using something like :-

```
 val mydb = CommonClass.openSQLDatabase(this)
```